# How to call cache:clear command with argumemt within another command - Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I know that I can run a command within another command.
like this example..

```
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('cache:clear');
    $arguments = array();
    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);
    $text = '';
    if ($returnCode != 0) {
        $text .= 'successfully...';
    }

    $output->writeln($text);
```

But when I trying to run the cache:clear command with their options-

```
$arguments = array(
        '--env=prod' => true
    );
```

I get the following error

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidOptionException]
  The "--env=prod" option does not exist.
```

How can I run this command?

Comment: `'env' => 'prod'` ?

Comment: Got the error `The "env" argument does not exist`

Comment: This isn't possible in this way. I think the env option is created in an EventListener that fires on console.command afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like:

```
$arguments = array(
    '--env' => 'prod',
);
```

Comment: it runs the dev environment

Comment: Clearing dev would be without the `--env=prod`? This answer should be correct.

Comment: I try to call clear:cache from another Command, but using ['--env' => 'prod'] running my command, the clear:cache command return "// Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true"

Answer (score 0):

`--` is only needed when passing an *option*, not an argument.

To make your command able to consider your argument, just use:

```
$arguments = ['env' => 'prod'];
```

If it doesn't work, simply use `$input->setArgument('env', 'prod');`

Comment: Still getting the error `The "env" argument does not exist`